# how to display an ontology in an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an ontology as a tree in an HTML page and then make a drag and drop.

I want to let the user be able to drag a a vertex from this tree. Something like the tree in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hierarchical-treeview-in-python-gui-application/

I cannot find a plugin other than `jOWL`.

Is there a good plugin to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for functionality to drag-and-drop within the tree?  Something like: https://gojs.net/extras/treeViewEditor.html ?

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods yes.  But I dont know if there are any libarairy that can convert directly an ontology like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

D3.js: This is a JavaScript library for creating interactive data visualizations. You can use it to create a tree diagram of an ontology and enable drag-and-drop functionality through the use of event listeners.

GoJS: This is a JavaScript library for creating interactive diagrams and graphs. It includes support for creating tree diagrams and enabling drag-and-drop functionality.

cytoscape.js: is a JavaScript library for creating graph theory (network) models on the web, it's also support tree diagrams and draggable nodes

Vis.js: is a JavaScript library for creating interactive data visualizations. It includes support for creating tree diagrams and enabling drag-and-drop functionality.